# .Net Enterprise Library -- an instance of eventsource with guid already exists

Tags: c#, enterprise-library

Problem I am working on is that I need to create separate log files for each thread. but when I create multiple instance of observable listener, I see an error that instance of Event Source already exists and I did some research and got to know that we can only have one instance of Event Source. Is there any work around on how to Log into separate log files.

Code Snippet

```
ObservableEventListener listener1 = new ObservableEventListener();
Logger logger1 = new Logger();
listener1.EnableEvents(logger1, EventLevel.LogAlways, Keywords.All);
listener1.LogToFlatFile("LogFile1.txt");

logger1.Informational("HELLO1");

listener1.DisableEvents(logger1);
listener1.Dispose();

ObservableEventListener listener2 = new ObservableEventListener();
Logger logger2 = new Logger();
listener2.EnableEvents(logger2, EventLevel.LogAlways, Keywords.All); -- Here I see an error
listener2.LogToFlatFile("LogFile2.txt");

logger2.Informational("HELLO2");
listener2.DisableEvents(logger1);
listener2.Dispose();
```

Answer (score 3):

The error is occuring because there are multiple instances of `Logger` being used (which is an `EventSource`).  There can only be one instance of a specific EventSource used.  The usual approach to avoid this is to make the EventSource a singleton:

```
[EventSource(Name = "MyCompany-Logger")]
public sealed class Logger : EventSource
{
    private static readonly Lazy<Logger> Instance = new Lazy<Logger>(() => new Logger());

    private Logger() { }

    public static Logger Log
    {
        get { return Instance.Value; }
    }

    // ...
}
```